# How do python resolve package names when Monkey Patching

Tags: python, import, python-import, monkeypatching, sys.path

I learn that python will make sure to input each package **only once** by appending the `__name__` of each imported (either directly or indirectly ) package  to `sys.path` only once.

I'm currently working with **monkey patch** in python, and I want to make sure I can always make the right change.

Say there's a function in a multi-layer package `packageA.subB.subC.moduleFoo.func`, I have a file named `patch.py`, which implements a monkey patch function to modify `func`:

```
import packageA.subB.subC.moduleFoo

def new_func():
    pass

def modifier():
    packageA.subB.subC.moduleFoo.func = newfunc
```

In my current script, I import `packageA.subB.subC.moduleFoo` as well as file `patch.py`. I want to use the `modifier` function in the current python script.

I'm wondering whether as long as I correctly access `func` in both the current script and `patch.py`, my modifier function will work properly. If the answer is yes, what will be stored in `sys.path` in the main script to help make this all right?

(Note that there're multiple ways to import a function from a multi-layer package, for example:

```
import packageA.subB.subC.moduleFoo # access with packageA.subB.subC.moduleFoo.func
from packageA.subB.subC import moduleFoo # access with moduleFoo.func
from packageA.subB.subC.moduleFoo import func
```